# XMLloader using pig latin

Tags: regex, xml, apache-pig

```
<user>

<ids>
<id>
456
</id>
<id>
123
</id>
</ids>

<username>
Taylor
</username>
</user>
```

the above one runs successfully but 0 records stored

please help me on this

Comment: input is 
<user>
<id>
456
</id>
<username>
Taylor
</username>
</user>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `singleline` mode option for `.` to match a newline, or `[\\s\\S]*` to work around it:

```
B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x, '<user>\\n\\s*<id>([\\s\\S]*)</id>\\n\\s*<username>([\\s\\S]*)</username>\\n\\s*</user>'))
```

Or even omitting `\n` since `\s` already captures it:

```
B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x, '<user>\\s*<id>([\\s\\S]*)</id>\\s*<username>([\\s\\S]*)</username>\\s*</user>'))
```

Comment: please can you help in how do we add the sinle line mode for . to match the new line..
is the (?s) you have used for that ?

Comment: great ..thanks
what is the actuall significance of using \\n\\s*

Comment: The pattern `\n\s*` makes sense if you want to match a newline *obligatorily*, and then any whitespace, any number of repetitions. In your case, in XML, it makes no sense since you are not trying to match specific lines in the input string.

Comment: hi..still getting the same..0 records stored..any alternative solution?

Comment: Did you try with single slashes? I have noticed the usage of single slashes in the documentation, but you said your code worked well, so I thought double ones were working in your case.

Comment: ya double slashes are working fine but 0 records processed
.single slashes gives lexical error.

Comment: i haven't pasted the actual xml file..here..its just a sample..cant send out here..any email id on which i can send on the input and latin statements (the original ones)?

Comment: I think there is no problem with regex the. Is there any reason to use flatten here?You will get only a non-nested tuples. I am afraid I won't be able to debug the whole code. :(

Comment: i'll change the input a bit

Comment: changed the input..now..any clue ?

Comment: Yes, regex didn't match the values. Try `(?s)<user>.*?<id>\\s*([^>]*?)\\s*</id>.*?<username>\\s*([^>]*?)\\s*</username>`.

Comment: its runs successfully.says 1 record processed .but the output tuple is empty

Comment: Try not flattening it. The `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` function already returns a tuple.